# Is assignment atomic in Promela?

Tags: formal-methods, software-verification

Is assignment atomic is Promela?  That is, can concurrent

```
x = value1;
```

and

```
x = value2;
```

produce anything different from value1 or value2 ?

And can a concurrent execution of

```
x = expression1;
```

and

```
x = expression2;
```

produce anything else than the values of expression1 and expression2, executed atomically (especially if reading more than one variable in any of the expressions)?

I failed to find a clear, straight statement about this in http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/Manual.html , http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/assign.html , or http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/Quick.html . The text says that the assignments are *basic* (i.e., without substatements), but does not say anything about the semantics of *basic*.

(PS. Of course, we know that, in the first place, Promela code is not meant to be actually executed, though `printf`s and translators to C exist; no question about that.)

Comment: If `x` is of basic datatype (say 32bit integer), then assignment is atomic since it is implemented by a single machine instruction in modern CPUs.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, on CPUs. And what the modern CPUs do is, strictly speaking, unrelated. Promela is a specification language of its own.